# What is the time complexity of checking membership in dict.items()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of checking membership in dict.items()?

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.
> **If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and**
> **hashable, then the items view is also set-like.** (Values views are not
> treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For
> set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base
> class collections.abc.Set are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

So I did some testing with the following code:

```py
from timeit import timeit

def membership(val, container):
    val in container

r = range(100000)
s = set(r)
d = dict.fromkeys(r, 1)
d2 = {k: [1] for k in r}
items_list = list(d2.items())

print('set'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership(-1, s), number=1000))
print('dict'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership(-1, d), number=1000))
print('d_keys'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership(-1, d.keys()), number=1000))
print('d_values'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership(-1, d.values()), number=1000))
print('\n*With hashable dict.values')
print('d_items'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership((-1, 1), d.items()), number=1000))
print('*With unhashable dict.values')
print('d_items'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership((-1, 1), d2.items()), number=1000))
print('d_items'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership((-1, [1]), d2.items()), number=1000))
print('\nitems_list'.ljust(12), end='')
print(timeit(lambda: membership((-1, [1]), items_list), number=1000))
```

With the output:

```
set         0.00034419999999998896
dict        0.0003307000000000171
d_keys      0.0004200000000000037
d_values    2.4773092

*With hashable dict.values
d_items     0.0004413000000003109
*With unhashable dict.values
d_items     0.00042879999999989593
d_items     0.0005549000000000248

items_list  3.5529328
```

As you can see, when the `dict.values` are all hashable (`int`),
the execution time for the membership is similar to that of a `set` or `d_keys`,
because *items view is set-like*.
The last two examples are on the `dict.values` with unhashable objects (`list`).
So I assumed the execution time would be similar to that of a `list`.
However, they are still similar to that of a `set`.

Does this mean that even though `dict.values` are unhashable objects,
the implementation of *items view* is still very efficient,
resulting *O(1)* time complexity for checking the membership?

Am I missing something here?

**EDITED**
per @chepner's comment: `dict.fromkeys(r, [1])` -> `{k: [1] for k in r}`
**EDITED**
per @MarkRansom's comment: another test case `list(d2.items())`

Comment: I don't think `in` checks the values for membership, so it wouldn't matter if the values were hashable or not.

Comment: @MarkRansom Are you saying python internally checks only the first item of every tuples? `items` return a view object consisting `(key, value)` pairs as tuple.

Comment: Keep in mind that `dict.fromkeys(r, [1])` creates a `dict` with only one *unique* value; for any two keys `x` and `y`, `d2[x] is d2[y]` will be true. That may be related.

Comment: @chepner Maybe, I'll try it with different objects.

Comment: @chepner That wasn't the issue. See the edited code.

Comment: An interesting addition to your experiment would be to run it against `list(d2.items())`.

Comment: @Mark What would that add exactly? `(k, v) in list(d2.items())` will of course be O(n), and OP is already checking `v in d2.values()`, which is also O(n).

Comment: @wjandrea it would confirm that `dict_items` has an optimized lookup that is *not* O(n).

Comment: @MarkRansom I think what I have already still confirms that, but I'll add that anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lookup in an instance of `dict_items` is an O(1) operation (though one with an arbitrarily large constant, related to the complexity of comparing values.)

---

[`dictitems_contains`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4692) doesn't simply try to hash the tuple and look it up in a set-like collection of key/value pairs.

(Note: all of the following links are just to different lines of `dictitems_contain`, if you don't want to click on them individually.)

To evaluate

```
(-1, [1]) in d2.items()
```

it first [extracts the key from the tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4701), then tries to [find that key in the underlying `dict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4703). If that lookup [fails](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4703), it immediately [returns false](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4707). Only if the key is found does it then [compare the value from the tuple to the value mapped to the key in the dict](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L4710).

At no point does `dictitems_contains` need to hash the second element of the tuple.

It's not clear in what ways an instance of `dict_items` is *not* set-like when the values are non-hashable, as mentioned in the documentation.

---

A simplified, pure-Python implementation of `dict_items.__contains__` might look something like

```
class DictItems:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def __contains__(self, t):
        key = t[0]
        value = t[1]
        try:
            dict_value = self.d[key]  # O(1) lookup
        except KeyError:
            return False
    
        return value == dict_value  # Arbitrarily expensive comparison

    ...
```

where `d.items()` returns `DictItems(d)`.

Comment: So to answer the question in the title, that makes it O(1) + comparison time (i.e. `found.__eq__(value)`), right?

Comment: Is this speculation, or did you go to the source?

Comment: Regarding a non-set-like `dict_items`: `{0} | {1: []}.items()` -> `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. While a set-like one works: `{0} | {1: 2}.items()` -> `{0, (1, 2)}`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't trace all the functional dependencies in the answer, but in short, `dk_lookup` is used both by `dict_subscript` (which is what implements `dict.__getitem__`) and `PyDict_GetItemWithError` (which is what `dictitems_contains` uses).

Comment: Thanks! This perfectly explains the execution times of the code. Thanks for the source code reference!

Answer (score 14):

### Short-answer

The time complexity of membership testing in item views is `O(1)`.

### Psuedo-code for lookup

This is how the membership testing works:

```
def dictitems_contains(dictview, key_value_pair):
    d = dictview.mapping
    k, v = key_value_pair
    try:
        return d[k] == v
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

### Actual Code

Here's the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/dictobject.c#L4402):

```
static int
dictitems_contains(_PyDictViewObject *dv, PyObject *obj)
{
    int result;
    PyObject *key, *value, *found;
    if (dv->dv_dict == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (!PyTuple_Check(obj) || PyTuple_GET_SIZE(obj) != 2)
        return 0;
    key = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(obj, 0);
    value = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(obj, 1);
    found = PyDict_GetItemWithError((PyObject *)dv->dv_dict, key);
    if (found == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }
    Py_INCREF(found);
    result = PyObject_RichCompareBool(found, value, Py_EQ);
    Py_DECREF(found);
    return result;
}
```

### Timing evidence for O(1) complexity

We get the same constant lookup time regardless of the dictionary size (in these cases: 100, 1,000, and 10,000).

```
$ python3.8 -m timeit -s 'd = dict.fromkeys(range(100))'  '(99, None) in d.items()'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 92 nsec per loop

$ python3.8 -m timeit -s 'd = dict.fromkeys(range(1_000))'  '(99, None) in d.items()'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 92.2 nsec per loop

$ python3.8 -m timeit -s 'd = dict.fromkeys(range(10_000))'  '(99, None) in d.items()'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 92.1 nsec per loop
```

### Evidence that lookup calls hash()

We can monitor hash calls by patching *_*hash*_()*:

```
class Int(int):
    def __hash__(self):
        print('Hash called')
        return hash(int(self))
```

Applying the monitoring tool show that hashing occurs when the dictionary is created and again when doing membership testing on the items view:

```
>>> d = {Int(1): 'one'}
Hash called
>>> (Int(1), 'one') in d.items()
Hash called
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Especially on `hash()` call when lookup in `items view` with hashable values.